# php sends charset header but there is no header command

Tags: php, character-encoding, header

My browser shows page with incorrect encoding. I have figured out that the server sends headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2014 18:21:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.2.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12
Content-Length: 4
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
```

but `php` script doesn't contain encoding set command. I even added `exit` on the script top and browser still getting `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`. How so?

Comment: Apache will still send out headers to respond to the request.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are plenty of ways to modify the header php sends...

Comment: Did you try use? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at `default_charset` in `php.ini`. Leave it empty if you do not want a Content-Type header.

In PHP one always can do a `header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');`.

Apache also has a config for Content-Type, but the error probably lies at the PHP side.